# How to do a responsive navigation in Angular 2?

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I know how to do it using vanilla CSS with JS. However I'm having troubles doing it in Angular 2.

Putting routing aside, this is how my component looks so far.

**navbar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent {
  menuIcon = '☰';
  isCollapsed = true;

  constructor() { }

  onInit() {

  }

  public toggleNav() {
    this.isCollapsed = !this.isCollapsed;
    console.log(`Botton menu clicked`);
    !this.isCollapsed ? this.menuIcon = '✖' : this.menuIcon = '☰';
   // return this.menuIcon;
  }

}
```

**navbar.component.html**

```
<nav>
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="#" (click)="toggleNav()" id="menu__icon">{{menuIcon}}</a></li>
    <span *ngIf="!isCollapsed">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </span>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**navbar.component.css**

```
.navigation {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;

  background: #111;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
}

.navigation a:hover {
  background: lighten(#111, 15%);
}

@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
  .navigation {
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}


.navigation #menu__icon {
    display: none;
  }



@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navigation {
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .navigation a {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  }

  .navigation li:last-of-type a {
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  .navigation #menu__icon {
    display: block;
  }

}

 .navigation #menu__icon a {
    color: tomato;
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
```

So far, it looks as I want in mobile devides. How do I make it show in a row on bigger viewports?

Answer (score 0):

using bootstrap in Angular2 and typescript.

> npm install --save bootstrap

update .angular-cli.json
add bootstrap link to styles section

> "styles": [
>           "styles.css",
>           "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" ]

Then follow this link [here](https://medium.com/@ct7/the-simple-way-to-make-a-mobile-angular-2-bootstrap-navbar-without-jquery-d6b3f67b037b)